# Limit check_box_tags in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm using the check_box_tag to setup checkboxes in my rails app (in an html.erb file, within a form) and i want to limit the user to selecting a maximum of 2. How can i achieve this?

```
<% if @users != nil %>
    <% @users.each do |u| %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]' , u.id %>
        <%= label_tag 'user_ids[]', u.name %> <br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it at the time of creating your checkboxes - ie, in the code you've pasted above.

You'd have to check it in the browser using javascript - when the user checks more than two checkboxes, you can show some kind of error in the browser.

You should also check the limit of two checkboxes server-side - when your form is submitted, you can return an error and not save the changes if more than two checkboxes are checked.

But just to re-iterate, it's not a feature that's built in to html itself, so when you're creating your checkboxes in the view file, you can't limit it to 2 at that point.